# Vertica connection to Dbeaver Error - Index 1 out of bound length 1

Tags: jdbc, vertica, dbeaver

While trying to connect Dbeaver to Vertica, I keep getting the below error:

//
Can't create driver instance
Error creating driver 'Vertica' instance.
Most likely required jar files are missing.
You should configure jars in driver settings.

Reason: can't load driver class 'com.vertica.jdbc.Driver'
Error creating driver 'Vertica' instance.
Most likely required jar files are missing.
You should configure jars in driver settings.

Reason: can't load driver class 'com.vertica.jdbc.Driver'
ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
//

I tried using different JDBC drivers versions but the error remains the same.
I am using MacBookPro with M1 Pro.

I would appreciate any pointers to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Client Drivers team at Vertica.  The problem most likely has to do with the JVM on your M1 macbook.  If you try `java -version` do you get a number like 1.7.0_261 or 17?  An M1 macbook will have the open JDK and you will have the simpler version numbering scheme.  The Vertica JDBC driver has a bug and does not work with the newer style of version numbers used by JVMs like the one for the open JDK.

As a work around, if you can get a JVM that uses the 1.7 style versioning, that should prevent this from happening. It may be that the Open JDK is the only JVM you can use.

We have also fixed the issue in our latest driver code and plan to release it in our next release, which is due out in a few months.  Our drivers are backwards compatible with older versions of Vertica, so you will be able to use the new driver without updating the Vertica server.  See [Vertica Client Drivers](https://www.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/)

Lastly, if your organization has a Vertica support plan, you can submit a support request on this issue.  You will get notified when there is a driver you can download that resolves the issue.